# Why am I getting this error? I don't understand what is typerror

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

I am getting:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type (s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType

error in factorial program. Can anyone please help me out..

```
def factorial(n):
     if n == 0:
         return 1
     if n > 1:
         return n*factorial(n -1)

print(factorial (5))
```

Comment: You don't seem to be handling the conditions well here: what happens when `n == 1`? Try: `factorial = lambda n: 1 if n == 0 else n * factorial(n-1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you start at `factorial(2)`, and what does the function return when `n == 1`?

If no return statement is hit, the function implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: Yeah.. that's the reason... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

change `n > 1` to `n >= 1` since in the recursion there is no case for n = 1.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe `n == None` to check it just do a

```
if n == None:
    print("n == None")
```

if you are sure that it is not null cast it as an int: `n = int(n)`

EDIT None and not null long time since I coded in python

Comment: `null` does not exist in python

Comment: This still doesn't help. The problem is that it *shouldn't be* None; just finding out if it is doesn't fix anything.